# Why PHP web service returning "You did not select a file to upload" when trying to upload a file using Android App?

Tags: php, android, image, codeigniter, file-upload

I am creating an Android App which having a functionality that uploads an image file a server using PHP web service.

**My Problem**
When I uploading the Image selected from gallery and after it sent to web service using Async URL execuation , the PHP web service returning the following message::

> [{"status":"Fail","message":{"error":"
>
> You did not select a file to
>   upload.
>
> "}}]

**Conditions I checked:**

- The Android App have file access permissions
- The image file is not corrupted
- The file Upload drive don't have any saving problems
- The selected image is temporarily displaying in ImageView addresed by local storage

**My Question** 
 Why did this error happen? What are the ways to recify this?

**My Android Async Task Code**:

- Function called inside Asyc's doInBackground:

  ```
       protected void Upload_Server() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      System.out.println("Image Upload :: After call progress");
      try{

          Log.e("Image Upload", "Inside Upload");

          HttpURLConnection connection;
          DataOutputStream outputStream;

          String pathToOurFile = picturePath;
          //    String pathToOurFile1 = imagepathcam;

          System.out.println("Image Upload : Before Image Upload"+picturePath);

        //  String urlServer=Constants.LIVEURL+"imageUpload/";
          String urlServer=Constants.LIVEURL+"imageUpload/";
          System.out.println("Image Upload : URL SETVER"+urlServer);
          System.out.println("Image Upload : After Image Upload"+picturePath);
          String lineEnd = "\r\n";
          String twoHyphens = "--";
          String boundary =  "*****";

          int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
          byte[] buffer;
          int maxBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;

          FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile));
          //  FileInputStream fileInputStream1 = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile1));

          URL url = new URL(urlServer);
          connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
          System.out.println("Image Upload : URL is "+url);
          System.out.println("Image Upload ; connection is "+connection);
          // Allow Inputs & Outputs
          connection.setDoInput(true);
          connection.setDoOutput(true);
          connection.setUseCaches(false);
          connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
          // Enable POST method
          connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

          connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
          connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

          outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
          outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
          outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile +"\"" + lineEnd);
          outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

          bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
          bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
          buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

          // Read file
          bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

          while (bytesRead > 0)
          {
              outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
              bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
              bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
              bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
          }

          outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
          outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

          // Responses from the server (code and message)
          int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
          String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

          System.out.println("Image Upload : image"+serverResponseMessage);

          fileInputStream.close();
          outputStream.flush();
          outputStream.close();

          DataInputStream inputStream1;
          inputStream1 = new DataInputStream (connection.getInputStream());
          String str;
          String Str1_imageurl="";

          while ((  str = inputStream1.readLine()) != null)
          {
              Log.e("Image Upload : Debug","Server Response "+str);

              Str1_imageurl = str;
              Log.e("Image Upload : Debug","Server Response String imageurl"+str);
          }
          inputStream1.close();
          System.out.println("Image Upload : image url"+Str1_imageurl);

          //get the image url and store
          profImage=Str1_imageurl.trim();
          JSONArray array = new JSONArray(profImage);
          JSONObject jsonObj  = array.getJSONObject(0);
          System.out.println("Image Upload : image name"+jsonObj.getString("image_name"));

          profileImageNew=jsonObj.optString("image_name");

          System.out.println("Image Upload : Profile Picture Path"+profImage);
      }

      catch(Exception e){

          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  ```

**PHP Web Service Function**

```
public function imageUpload_post()
  {
    $status = "";
    $msg = "";

    $file_element_name = 'uploadedfile';
    if ($status != "error")
    {
    //  $config['upload_path'] = '/var/ftp/virtual_users/tastenote/tastenote.com/files/gastronote/';
    $config['upload_path'] = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/images'; //Set the upload path
    //$config['upload_path'] = '/opt/lampp/htdocs/celebspot.git/files/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|JPEG|PNG|JPG'; // Set image type
    $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE; // Change image name

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if(!$this->upload->do_upload($file_element_name)){
    $status = 'error';
    $msg = $this->upload->display_errors('','');
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $final['status']="Fail";
    $final['message']= $error ;
    //print_r($error);
    $data = "";
    }
    else {

    $data = $this->upload->data(); // Get the uploaded file information

    $this->load->library('image_lib');

    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/images/'.$data['raw_name'].$data['file_ext'];
    $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;

    $config['width']     = 125;
        $config['height']   = 125;

           $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
           $this->image_lib->resize();
           $final['status']="Success";
           $final['imageurl']= $this->config->item('base_url').'images/'.$data['raw_name'].$data['file_ext'];
           $final['image_name']= $data['raw_name'].$data['file_ext'];
    //echo $this->config->item('base_url').'images/'.$data['raw_name'].$data['file_ext'];
    //echo '[{"status":"Success","imageurl":"'.$this->config->item('base_url').'images/'.$data['raw_name'].$data['file_ext'].'"}]';
    }

    @unlink($_FILES[$file_element_name]);
        print_r(json_encode(array($final),JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));exit;
    }

  }
```

When on execution the Android App prints the following logs in logcat:

> 11-16 11:47:11.855 22421-22873/com.nuvo.driver I/System.out: Image
>   Upload :: After call progress
>
> 11-16 11:47:11.856 22421-22873/com.nuvo.driver I/System.out: Image
>   Upload : Before Image Upload/storage/sdcard0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp
>   Images/IMG-20171112-WA0002.jpg
>
> 11-16 11:47:11.856 22421-22873/com.nuvo.driver I/System.out: Image
>   Upload : URL
>   SETVERhttp://demo.cogzideltemplates.com/nuvo/driver/imageUpload/
>
> 11-16 11:47:11.857 22421-22873/com.nuvo.driver I/System.out: Image
>   Upload : After Image Upload/storage/sdcard0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp
>   Images/IMG-20171112-WA0002.jpg
>
> 11-16 11:47:11.858 22421-22873/com.nuvo.driver I/System.out: Image
>   Upload : URL is
>   http://demo.cogzideltemplates.com/nuvo/driver/imageUpload/
>
> 11-16 11:47:11.858 22421-22873/com.nuvo.driver I/System.out: Image
>   Upload ; connection is
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl:http://demo.cogzideltemplates.com/nuvo/driver/imageUpload/
>
> 11-16 11:47:28.435 22421-22873/com.nuvo.driver I/System.out: Image
>   Upload : imageOK
>
> 11-16 11:47:28.447 22421-22873/com.nuvo.driver I/System.out: Image
>   Upload : image url[{"status":"Fail","message":{"error":"
>
> You did not
>   select a file to upload.
>
> "}}]

Note the last line **You did not select file to upload** error message.

- This is the problem. I tried to resolve but I can't . Please tell a
  soultion to recitify this.

Comment: How this question not related to programming? Why are you closing this?

Comment: Try with the POSTMAN addon for chrome and check whether the same result?

Comment: `PHP Web Service Function`. Show complets code. Show the code which calls this function.

Comment: `Conditions I checked`. That is not enough. And the most important 'did i sent a file correct?' is missing.

Comment: `connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);` Remove that.

Comment: `filename=\"" + pathToOurFile +"\""`. You should only supply a file name. Not a full path.

Comment: `Note the last line You did not select file to upload error message`. Note that this error message is nowhere to be found in the php code you posted.

Comment: Ok. I will check your suggestions and reply to you .Thanks